# hash navigation URL construction

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

Let's say that `location.href` is `http:/domain.com/en/` at the moment.

After a click I want it to be `http://domain.com/en/#opened-File.html/1`

This way I know what URL I need, so if a user copies and shares this URL I am doing:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var info = window.location.hash.match(/^#([^\/]*)\/([^-]*)-(.*)$/),
        url="", nivel="", seccion="";
    if (info) {
        url = info[1];
        nivel = info[3];
        seccion = info[2];
        location.href = url;
    }
}
```

Wich works fine, but my questions are:

- is this a good aproach?
- is this seo-frendly?
- would you do it differently?

this works together with

```
$('nav a').each(function(){
        if(!$(this).hasClass('enlaceAnulado')){
        /*Recopilamos*/
            var href = $(this).attr('href');
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var parts = id.split("_");
            var seccion = parts[0];
            var nivel = parseInt(parts[1])+1;
        /*Quitamos el enlace*/
            $(this).attr('href','javascript:void(0)');
        /*Guardamos la información.*/
            $(this).data('hrefnot',href);
            $(this).data('nivel',nivel);
            $(this).data('seccion',seccion);
            $(this).addClass('enlaceAnulado');
        }
    });
```

So the links where static but i do this to improve user experience and load content via ajax

Comment: I've suggested an edit to your post. In it, I added a missing `}`. Since the code "works fine", I assumed this typo snuck in while posting the question. If this is not the case, please revert the edit.

Answer (score 1):

Search engine indexes your page content as if the url has nothing that follows the hash. Hash navigation is only intended for the browser to maintain a navigation history. You should always make the content you want to be indexed static. Consider this as an answer to all three questions of yours.

Comment: edited question to clarify what i am doing, maybe having a look to the site will make have more sense: http://toniweb.us/gm

Comment: You should understand that changing the content with visual transitions does not improve the user experience; frankly it is even often considered irritating. Since in your case there was no other reason to make the content dynamic, my opinion is that the only proper choice would be making it static and providing it with links like "/en/about", "/en/gallery/" and etc

Comment: it's not really my call... :(

Answer (score 0):

> is this a good approach?

My first inclination is to think that this is a good job for the server-side (php, python, asp.net, apache rewrite, etc.)

> is this seo-frendly?

I would worry about the hash, and instead utilize better Url practices.

> would you do it differently?

I would rather have my server parse (mod rewrite, etc) the Url instead of javascript.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to add the following to Nikita Volkov's answer:

Search crawlers generally don't run JavaScript code (although Google is [trying to change that](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/5653/does-the-google-spider-render-javascript)). This means that redirecting the user to a static page using JavaScript, like what you're doing with this:

```
location.href = url;
```

...is not going to work.

If you want to make URL's with hash tags more SEO-friendly, you'll have to do it server-side.

Comment: but please note that that will only happen in the case the user shares the link FROM his own navigation. because google should read the normal URL